# jsoup parsing tr android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I tried to parse this html
how can one parse it with jsoup ?
I would like to get everything between < td>*< /td> tags :

```
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><h1><a rel='bookmark' href="http://google.com">google</a></h1></td>
        <td><font face=tahoma size=2>2014</td></font>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ..
    </tr>

    <tr>
        ..
    </tr>

</table>
```

---

```
URL url= new URL("http://mylink.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).userAgent("Mozila").get();
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I parsed the `td` from the table using `doc.select("td");`

```
String html = "<table border=\"0\" align=\"center\">"
    +"<tr>"
        +"<td><h1><a rel='bookmark' href=\"http://google.com\">google</a></h1></td>"
        +"<td><font face=tahoma size=2>2014</td></font>";
          Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
          Elements element=doc.select("td");
          for(Element ele:element){
         log.d("el","ele.text()");//text() to print in between the text //text() to print in between the text 
          }
```